localhost:80 keeps switching to localhost:50822 when browsing Wordpress index.php
I'm using a windows 2012 cloud server and running multiple websites on IIS, including a Wordpress site.  I'm attempting to set up another Wordpress site and have set everything just like the previous Wordpress site, but it isn't working.  When I browse to http://localhost/folder/default.aspx, it browses successfully (I think it's using the default port of 80 correctly)...the default.aspx was my test "hello world" page.  But when I browse to the Wordpress start page, index.php, the url is forwarded from "http://localhost/folder/default.aspx" to "http://localhost:50822/folder/index.php" and it fails I get the error "localhost refused to connect".  I recently created a completely different project within Visual Studio, an ASP.NET Web Core project and I suspect that that somehow altered something on my server, but am not sure.  I did finally notice that the port being used in the VS project was 50822.  So I stopped the IIS server to release 80, changed the VS project to use 80, ran the project once or twice to build the project, shutdown the project, and restarted the IIS server.  But the result is the same.  Any ideas?
Per the suggestion, I've included the relevant portion of the applicationhost.config below:
   <listenerAdapters>
        <add name="http" />
    </listenerAdapters>

    <sites>
        <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <!-- To enable logging, please change the below attribute "enabled" to "true" -->
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%AppData%\Microsoft\IISExpressLogs" enabled="false"/>
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%AppData%\Microsoft" enabled="false" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>


You will have to open up applicationHost.config and edit this question to include the contents of <sites> tag. Besides, you should move away from PHP on IIS https://docs.lextudio.com/phpmanager/getting-started/supported-platforms#php-on-windows-status and the end-of-life Windows Server 2012.

Thank you for the advice.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck with WinSvr2012 for now and my other PHP apps run on IIS with no issues.  The suggestion to check the applicationHost.config file was spot on, though, and I saw the 50822 sitting in the project properties.  So the creation of that other project must have altered something and disallows me from using that URL anymore, even though I've updated the applicationHost.config file.  Not sure why it doesn't release it...maybe cached somewhere?

You got the wrong config file. I was asking about full IIS, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/getting-started/iis#local-iis-server If you have VS installed on this server, but not pointing a web project to full IIS, then VS shouldn't interference.

Found the problem:  the prior project, done in VS ASP.NET Core, stored the 50822 port in the WordPress database.  So, despite changing the project properties, or even removing the project, every subsequent WP project which logged into the database was affected.  The solution was to drop the database schema and recreate it.
